# C# Can you control the opacity of client form but keep the parent & controls separate? preferably using dwmapi Glass also

Tags: c#, winforms

Can you make a form background clear, but keep the parent window & the controls on the form @ 100% opacity?

Comment: Set the TransparencyKey and BackColor of the form to, say, Color.Fuchsia.

Answer (score 0):

A form's background **is** of the parent window, they're the same thing. I think you should reword your question.

Anyway, the DWM API does not expose any facility to allow developers to change the opacity of the glass area, and in fact the Glass effect is completely gone in Windows 8, it's all opaque solid colours with no pixel-shaders.